# type mismatch occurs while the evaluated values are equal

Tags: functional-programming, idris, dependent-type

I'm a beginner in Idris and trying to make a code valid.

> Could you let me know the better place for noob questions on Idris?

```
filter : (elem -> Bool) -> Vect len elem -> (p: (Fin len) ** Vect (finToNat p) elem)
filter {len=S l} p xs = ((FZ {k=l}) ** [])
filter {len=S l} p (x::xs) =
  let (a ** tail) = filter {len=l} p xs
   in if p x then
        ((FS a) ** x::tail)
      else
        ((weaken a) ** tail)
```

I wrote another `filter` which can't pass the type check yet.

This new `filter`'s type implies that the filtered vector cannot be longer than the original one.

However, Idris saids

```
...
Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        finToNat a
                and
                        finToNat (weaken a)
```

We know those two terms always have the same value.

How can I describe the fact and let Idris say ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that `finToNat a = finToNat (weaken a)`. `tail` has type `Vect (finToNat a) elem`, but you need `Vect (finToNat (weaken a)) elem` for the second component in the last line, because you wrote `weaken a` in the first pair component.

```
lemma : {n : _} -> (a : Fin n) -> finToNat (weaken a) = finToNat a
lemma FZ     = Refl
lemma (FS x) = rewrite lemma x in Refl

filter : (elem -> Bool) -> Vect len elem -> (p: (Fin len) ** Vect (finToNat p) elem)
filter {len=S l} p xs = ((FZ {k=l}) ** [])
filter {len=S l} p (x::xs) =
  let (a ** tail) = Main.filter {len=l} p xs
  in if p x then
       ((FS a) ** x::tail)
     else
       (weaken a ** (rewrite lemma a in tail))
```